Platform Event Definition Bidirectional Architecture Best Practices
I need to use platform events to send and receive events to and from an external system.
I've implemented something similar in the past where I:

Created an OutboundEvent__e to send events to the external system
Created an InboundEvent__e to receive events from the same external system

I did not realize that Salesforce has a limit on the number of platform event definitions which makes this approach feel non-ideal.
I am now considering using one Event__e to handle both the inbound and outbound events, but I concerned about event publishing. It feels like an anti-pattern that the trigger subscribing to Event__e would pick up an outbound event. The trigger would not perform any action on outbound events, but it still feels non-ideal that it would subscribe to these outbound events.
I am wondering if there is a preferred method or any best practices for handling bidirectional communication using platform events?

I need to use platform events to send and receive events to and from an external system - questionable, see XY Problem. That aside,
https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration and https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/event-driven are a good read.

Thank you, that is a good read. There is a business requirement to use the event driven architecture.
